# Formatting C++ with a for loop

Tags: c++, format

I am going through a for loop and am wanting my output to look something like this:

```
apples_fuji      18.93    31.99
apples_gala      25.34    27.62
apples_jazz      16.77    36.73
apricots         17.92    22.22
bananas          25.87    18.63
cherries         16.30    78.40
grapes_red       15.62    41.86
grapes_white     23.06    86.94
pears_anjou      26.35    28.72
pears_bosc       12.03    15.52
plantains        16.35    23.54
watermelon       14.33    32.82

totals          228.87   444.99
```

unfortunately, it looks like this

```
apples_fuji            18.93  31.9917
apples_gala            25.34  27.6206
apples_jazz            16.77  36.7263
apricots            17.92  22.2208
bananas            25.87  18.6264
cherries            16.3  78.403
grapes_red            15.62  41.8616
grapes_white            23.06  86.9362
pears_anjou            26.35  28.7215
pears_bosc            12.03  15.5187
plantains            16.35  23.544
watermelon            14.33  32.8157
totals 228.87 444.987
```

where the first col is all strings and the second two are ints. What would be the best or easiest way to format it? I am having some trouble since the strings differ in length

```
int num;
int total_amount, tote_amount, tote_price;

for (int i=0; i < num; i++)
   cout << string "        " << num1 << " " << num2 <<endl;

cout << "totals"< < "    " << tote_amount << " " << tote_price <<endl;
```

Comment: maybe tabs would help "\t"; also fix the line in the for loop. `string "      "`

Comment: [setw](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) is what you need.

Comment: See stream modifiers:  precision, width and fill.  Search stackOverflow for "std::precision".

Answer (score 4):

If your strings have a maximum lenght, you can use

```
std::cout << std::setw(max_length) << std::setfill(' ') << left << value << ...
```

Answer (score 1):

> If your strings have a maximum lenght, you can use
>   std::cout << std::setw(max_length) << std::setfill(' ') << left << value << ...

If you don't know the maximum length, you can do something like this before (in C++11):

```
int maxLength = std::max_element(begin(names), end(names), 
                                 [](std::string const & a, std::string const & b) { return a.length() < b.length(); })->length();
```